# About a possible javascript and browser native capability to support sockets

Tags: javascript, browser

Even if my question is a generic one, it is bugging me for a while now, and I think it deserves some attention.

I wonder what might be the difficulties of implementing a native capability to support sockets for browsers. Meaning that javascript to be able to listen to an opened socket on some server that is specified, and be able to send packets to another that is listening. Without http request of course, that requires a lot of time to be wrapped, "headered" and so on. Thing that make a 10 ms request to one up to 400ms at least.

I understand that HTML is a text protocol and was not meant to be this way, but things have changed a lot lately,  and it is falling under it's own incapacity to support live applications and powerful streaming abilities that are so desired these days.

Even if we have seen it done in many ways, this has yet failed to reach browser developers attention as a viable solution for many problems, and a great feature.

So, my real question is why it is not yet implemented, and what does it need to be done in order for it to be possible.

I am aware that there are things like node.js, and sockets.io, and a lot of application that use ajax to simulate this, but nothing compares with a native and functional feature, the real deal.

Comment: The thing should be standardized and work the same in all browsers. That's why it's hard. We don't want no more browser wars.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, but from what we can see today IE started to be more "friendly" from this point of view (before it was the most non-standard browser) and have stopped for some time to swim against the wave. So we see that it is possible to manage doing something like this, besides, we shouldn't stop innovating just for the sake of having some "peace".

Comment: khael: why don't you join some w3c working groups and convince them to implement native sockets in all browsers? :-)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I was hoping to find something about why it might be a problem, before joining any w3c working group to convince them to revolutionize the web. (and it will sure be a great improvement)

Comment: I personally think that it's a collaboration issue.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev But besides the collaboration issue, are there any other problems?

Comment: And as a last final comment, as SO is already asking me to move this to the chat, I want to add that I totally love anonymous downvoters :) cheers.